# In SQL, how to concatenate string with integer data type column

Tags: sql, string-concatenation

I am trying to add string "Rs" with amount column. 
The data type of amount is integer.
But Sql is not allowing me to concatenate string with int data type column.[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMLvI.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C444M.png)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to explicitly convert the `int` to `varchar` before concatenating with any string

```
select 'RS'+cast(total_amount as varchar(100)),*
from yourtable
```

If you are sql server 2012+ then use `CONCAT` which does implicit conversion

```
select Concat('RS',total_amount),*
from yourtable
```

Comment: Thank you so much!